Is there a way to suppress the injection warning for @RestClient?
When I'm injecting a Quarkus Rest client through a constructor or a mock everything works fine, but  a pesky warning shows in my VsCode IDE.
The Rest Client object should have the @Inject and @RestClient annotations to be injected as a CDI bean.microprofile-restclient(InjectAndRestClientAnnotationMissing)

example code:
  private final CorrectionClient correctionClient;

  @Inject
  public CorrectionService(@RestClient CorrectionClient client) {
    this.correctionClient = client;
  }

From my understanding it's only cosmetic but it would still be nice fix it.
I've tried to add a @SuppressWarnings on it, but either it doesn't work or I don't use a correct name for it.
For my surprise there doesn't seem to be any valid google search results for it either.
Does anyone have a solution how to get rid of this false positive?
Tried to add a suppress warnings on it. Expected the warning to possibly disappear.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Do you have an extension like SonarLint installed?  They provide warning that there may be not accord with the specification and that potential errors can be optimized. Follow the warning that you need to add two annotations @Inject and @RestClient.You can disable the extension to resolve false positives for warnings if you need.

Good point with SonarLint. I'm indeed using it. But I almost certain it isn't it. The sonar warnings include a field that tells it's from the linter. This one does not. But it isn't a normal Java warning either. It seems to indicate it comes from microprofile-rest. Perhaps it's the microprofile extension then.

Will it still warning after add @RestClient? If it's a microprofile extension. You can try to resolve the issue by selecting the Disable (Workspace) option of the Tools for MicroProfile extension.
